# Unable to load csv using bq cli : "Failed to retrieve starting URI"

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to load data into a table using the bq cli but I keep getting the following error :

```
========================================
== Platform ==
  CPython:2.7.6:Linux-3.13.0-29-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
== bq version ==
  v2.0.14
== Command line ==
  ['/usr/local/bin/bq', '--service_account', 'xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com', '--service_account_private_key_file', 'keyfile.p12', '--service_account_credential_file', '../.bigquery.v2.token', 'load', 'xxxxxxxx', '/home/xxx/yyyy.csv.gz', '/home/xxx/schema.json']
== UTC timestamp ==
  2014-08-19 17:42:05
== Error trace ==
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bq.py", line 769, in RunSafely
    return_value = self.RunWithArgs(*args, **kwds)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bq.py", line 1003, in RunWithArgs
    job = client.Load(table_reference, source, schema=schema, **opts)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bigquery_client.py", line 1740, in Load
    upload_file=upload_file, **kwds)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bigquery_client.py", line 1452, in ExecuteJob
    job_id=job_id)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bigquery_client.py", line 1437, in RunJobSynchronously
    upload_file=upload_file, job_id=job_id)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bigquery_client.py", line 1431, in StartJob
    projectId=project_id).execute()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bigquery_client.py", line 279, in execute
    return super(BigqueryHttp, self).execute(**kwds)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/apiclient/http.py", line 656, in execute
    _, body = self.next_chunk(http=http)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/apiclient/http.py", line 733, in next_chunk
    raise ResumableUploadError("Failed to retrieve starting URI.")
========================================

Unexpected exception in load operation: Failed to retrieve starting URI.
```

My account has billing enable and I am able to do queries (other then load) using the bq cli.

Comment: can you post the line that triggered this error?

Comment: See my answer. Thanks for looking into it though

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer looking at an other post. I was missing the " --project_id" parameter. For any of the maintainer (though i'm thinking about doing it myself) it could be a good idea the refine the error message...